# Attempting to read raw database file

Tags: database, character-encoding, hex, flat-file, ctree

I'm attempting to read data from a database file (which employees c-tree data structure). This is a very old product, and for various reasons, the ODBC drivers are no longer available to me.

What I have found is that the data is basically just line-by-line "flat-file". So my plan is to simply read the raw binary data from the file, and in effect, fashion my own custom-built ODBC.

Using a tool provided by the the c-tree company themselves, I have even been able to get the details of each field address (i.e. where it starts), its length (length of the byte array) and a column that I assume is actually telling me how to field is encoded (see below):

```
ADDRESS  LENGTH  TYPE(encoding?)        FIELD NAME
0        8       (128-0x80) CT_ARRAY    Reserved
8        4       (59-0x3B) CT_INT4U     Record_ID
12       2       (41-0x29) CT_INT2U     Type
14       2       (41-0x29) CT_INT2U     Changes
16       52      (144-0x90) CT_FSTRING  Name
```

Am I correct in assuming that something like "(128-0x80)" should be the only information I need to decode the field into actual text? Or is it likely there's some further encryption that I'm not considering here?

Also could anyone tell me perhaps what exactly "(128-0x80)" is? I recognise the 0x80  as hex, but what does the 128 mean? With, at the very least, some kind of terminology to describe this thing, I could do some more google research.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will probably find there are `deleted` records in the file (with a flag indicating deleted/unused). It would be best to read the file with the supplied interface / utility program

Comment: As mentioned, this is not an option in my case.

Comment: You said ODBC was not an option. c-tree uses ISAM files with a c-program interface. Is the C interface available ?

Answer (score 0):

This type encoding is purely internal as our byte value representation of that data type.

For example: 80x (hex) = 128 (decimal) = data type CT_ARRAY and likewise for the others.

ADDRESS  LENGTH  TYPE(encoding?)        FIELD NAME

0        8       (128-0x80) CT_ARRAY    Reserved

8        4       (59-0x3B) CT_INT4U     Record_ID

12       2       (41-0x29) CT_INT2U     Type

14       2       (41-0x29) CT_INT2U     Changes

16       52      (144-0x90) CT_FSTRING  Name

You can view the data type descriptions online at documentation:  https://docs.faircom.com/doc/ctreeplus/28396.htm

It is likely this is a fixed length record. Variable length records will contain a 10-byte header on each which will need to be accounted for. Also, this appears to be a 1- or 2-byte (16 bit application) packed aligned data record, which should always be considered. Other C-structure compiler defined alignments will complicate data extraction.

The "Reserved" field could be simply the placeholder marker for our 1 byte deleted record mark and deleted record stack value (also described in our documentation). However, it could also contain application specific data relevant only to that application as it is 8 bytes long.

There should no other encryption or encoding of the data (certainly no Unicode).

Unfortunately, this ODBC Driver has been discontinued. There is a way for you to easily extract all data as it was intended with the c-treeACE database, but you will need to contact FairCom support for more information. The link for support is [faircom.com/support](https://www.faircom.com/support).